# How to do exception handling with nunit and moq?

Tags: nunit, nunit-2.5

I am trying to use nunits new way of exception handling but I am finding it hard to find information on it and how to also use it with moq.

I have right now moq that throws a exception on a mocked method but I don't know how to use nunit to catch it and look at it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a few different ways to do it; I use Assert.Throws.

```
var exception = Assert.Throws<YourTypeOfException>(()=> Action goes here);
```

e.g.

```
var exception = Assert
                .Throws<ArgumentNullException>(()=> new ChimpPuncher(null));
```

You can then query the exception object further if you want, e.g.

```
Assert.That(exception.Message, Text.Contains("paramname");
```

Answer (score 2):

Best way to mention is: `[ExpectedException(typeof(ApplicationException))]` above the test method.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that, if this type of Exception is thrown by _any_ part of the method that is decorated with the ExpectedException attribute, the test will pass. Using the Assert.Throws<> mechanism reduces the surface area, as the exception must be thrown within the method run by it.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you enclose the mocked method call in a try/catch block and catch the specific exception being thrown?